# Flexbox responsive last column floated and stacked

Tags: css, flexbox, frontend, responsive

Apologies for the cryptic title but not sure how to word this.  Wondering if this responsive layout is possible with flexbox.

I can easily do one or other - but I'm struggling to achieve below without creating two different html layouts.  Is this even possible?

[image: flexbox responsive layout]

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="2">Div 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">
    <div class="3">Div 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what css-grid was designed for.

Comment: tell that to IE...

Comment: You can't do this with flexbox without, at the very least,  fixed height column

Comment: you need grid and mediaquerie for this, about older IE, you also need to tell each div where to stand in the grid. all div have to be sibblings. display:contents is not an option for IE. Each display has its specifity and none includes magic :( You can also lay 2 grids on top of each others, but you may have some troubles  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rNaLZGB

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use [@media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to determine the size of the screen and adjust your sizing accordingly. Even then, sliding 3 under both 1 and 2 only on mobile might be quite the trick. Try using overflow to push it into the proper area. Most of that is basic CSS, though; you don't need flexbox for it.